# regex in postgresql function

Tags: regex, postgresql

I need to remove (by means of a function) possible non-latin characters (chinese, japanese, ...) by means of a regex expression from a Postgres database table.

I have tried all solutions I could find online, but nothing seems to work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.function_104(param text)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN  
    EXECUTE 'UPDATE public.' || quote_ident(param) || ' SET "name" = REGEXP_REPLACE("name", [^x00-x7F]+, " ")';

END
$function$
```

I keep running into following error message :

````
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: ..._roads_free_1 SET "name" = REGEXP_REPLACE("name", [^x00-x7F]...
                                                             ^
QUERY:  UPDATE public.gis_osm_roads_free_1 SET "name" = REGEXP_REPLACE("name", [^x00-x7F]+, " ")
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function afri_terra_104(text) line 6 at EXECUTE

```
````

Comment: I tried similar solutions : they always return similar errors

Comment: regardless of the regex expression validity, it must be put between single quotes. Same thing for the replacement value

Comment: in my case, I am only dealing with non-latin streetnames (= non-latin letters), but removing other non-ASCII punctuations and symbols okay

Comment: I put it between singles quotes, which used to work jut fine until I replaced the hard-coded datbase name by the param value.  from that momnt on, the '[' is causing issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put the regex between single quotes, as well as the replacement text. Since it is a dynamic query, you must escape the single quotes by doubling them:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.function_104(param text)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN  
    EXECUTE 'UPDATE public.' || quote_ident(param) || 
           ' SET "name" = REGEXP_REPLACE("name", ''[^x00-x7F]+'', '' '')';

END
$function$;


insert into t104(name) values('abcé');
INSERT 0 1

select function_104('t104');
 function_104
--------------

(1 row)

select * from t104;
 name
------
 abc
(1 row)
```